# Select the mode with the lowest value

Tags: python, string, mode

example of list [1,1,2,2,4,5]

the modes are 1 and 2.

if i use the mode function in statistics package in python, I get an error saying that there is no unique mode.

But I want the lower mode i.e. "1" to be printed.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps. **Edit:** Make `modes` a generator rather than a list. Thanks for comments from @codykochmann

```
from collections import Counter
nums = [7, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6]

c = Counter(nums) # count numbers
max_number_count = c.most_common(1)[0][1]
modes = (item for item, count in c.items() if count == max_number_count) 
min_mode = min(modes)
```

**When more numbers are added**:
Update the previous counter is easy. Say new numbers is `nums_2`, you can use `c.update(nums_2)` to update the counter `c` and then find the new minimum mode. Thanks for the inspiration from @Gautham Velchuru's answer.

Comment: Just a tiny nitpick but could you use `()` around modes instead of `[]`? Since `min` can evaluate generators and this dataset is only being evaluated once, it would save memory and be a clean example of when generators can cleanly be used where you would normally use a list compression :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tai. This solution is very simple and neat. I didn't know that there was a module for hashing and counting that could be used directly.

Comment: For counting, you can just use the one from `collections`, a standard library. For hashing, I am not so sure what you are looking into. Can you say more about that? I don't seem to use hashing in my method.

Answer (score 2):

[Scipy's mode](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html) does exactly that:

```
from scipy.stats import mode
m, c = mode([1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5])
```

Then `m` is the lowest mode (1) and `c` is its frequency (2).

Answer (score 0):

You could always roll your own - if the list is sorted you can keep a running mode and only update it when a new value is presented with more occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, but inefficient;

```
nums = [0,1,1]
nums = sorted([(x, -nums.count(x)) for x in set(nums)], key=lambda tup: tup[0])
nums.sort(key=lambda tup: tup[1])
print(nums[0][0])
```

Store a list of tuples with the val and count and sort that. Since sorts are least to greatest, you can multiply the count by -1.

Comment: Updated, sorry for that error I've been using too much pypy (which does weird things with sets)

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking this was a sorted puzzle, but then realized we only really cared about getting the smallest mode, so skip any indexing or tuple sorting with this to stay memory and speed happy.

```
from collections import Counter
nums = [7, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6]

c = Counter(nums)
max_count = max(c.values())
print(min(k for k,v in c.items() if v==max_count))
```